# How to parsing a json string within an array?

Tags: c#, json, parsing, serialization

I have problems with parsing JSON.

## JSON

```
[
 {
   "obj" :
    {
    "id" : 2001,
    "modified" : 1365551172.000000000,
    "size" : 19,
    }
 },{
   "obj2" :
    {
    "id" : 2001,
    "modified" : 1365551790.000000000,
    "size" : 19,
    }
 }
]
```

when I try to parse with

```
 var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, dynamic>>>(string);
 var json = jss.Serialize(dict);
```

there is an exception, that arrays couldn't be parsed.
Is there anything I have overseen ?
Is there any other library to use and how?

Comment: I believe it should be `var dict = jss.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, dynamic>>>>(string);`

Comment: You were right. Ok don't rely on resharper :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) ?

```
dynamic jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring); 

var id = jObj[0].obj.id;
```

or

```
var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(json);

var id = jObj[1]["obj2"]["system::ownerUserId"];
```